# Proving Summation logic

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, summation

for each integer $n$ with $n \geq 2$ let $p(n)$ be

$$p(n) =  \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i(i+1) = \frac{n(n-1)(n+1)}{(3)}$$

In the following example to prove P(2) is true.

I see $i=1$ is our starting bound, so plugging in $1(1+1) = 2$
and

$$\frac{2(2-1)(2+1)}{3}$$

is equal to $2$, so this works out.
What is tricking me is, if we carry this theory onto P(3) should I look to the upper bound $(n-1)$ and assign $i=2$ for the comparison?

Comment: I think you meant $2-1$ where you typed $2-2$

Comment: Yes I did, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that $i$ still starts to $1$ but goes also to $i=2$ because the upper bound is now $3-1=2$ :
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{3-1}i\left(i+1\right)=1\times2+2\times3=8
$$

and
$$
\frac{3\times2\times4}{3}=\frac{24}{3}=8
$$

You can try to do the case $n=4$ to make sure you have understood

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your help. Where does 1x2+2*3 come from? would it not just be 3(3+1) for p(3)

Comment: When you put $n=3$, that's not $i$ that directly takes the value $3$, it's the $n$ in the upper bound of the summation. It means you add one term to your sum. You sum $i\left(i+1\right)$ for $i$ starting from $1$ to $i=n-1$.

Comment: For example, $n=5$ means $1 \times 2 + 2\times 3 + 3 \times 4 + 4 \times 5$, do you see the difference with what you said ?

Comment: ahh okay, that makes sense. so how would you express P(k)?

Comment: The same way as you did, just putting $k$ instead of $n$

Comment: Thank you much.